# Is it possible to convert b'\x17\xf9' to 6137 in a single line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, hex

Is it possible to convert b'\x17\xf9' to 6137 in a single line in python or please can you suggest an efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Given `mybytes = b'\x17\xf9'`
you can do

```
mybytes[0]*256 + mybytes[1]
```

That gives 6137. If that's really all you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just in Case you have a byte string of variable length

```
mybytes = b'\x17\xf9'

sum(byte*(0x100**i) for i, byte in enumerate(reversed(mybytes)))
```